# Where to install C wire?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I need to run new thermostat wire since I don't have a C wire to power my smart thermostat, but need some guidance on where to hook it up. I have five wires at my thermostat, two going back to my furnace in the basement and the other three going to my attic where the A/C is located.

[image: thermostat]
[image: furnace]
[image: furnace]
[image: furnace]
[image: furnace]

Comment: Can you take the Nest base off and show us a closeup of the wiring coming out of the wall at the thermostat location, as well as a photos of the wiring at the air handler?

Answer (score 2):

On dual transformer systems, Nest expects the common wire to come from the cool side ([Nest Pro Guide, bottom of page 20](http://support-assets.nest.com/images/pro-faq/Nest-Pro-Installer-Guide.pdf)); look towards your A/C not your boiler.

If there is a common terminal on your A/C control board and

- 18/5 wire bundle - use one of the extra wires to connect the common terminal to your Nest
- 18/3 wire bundle

  - Use [Venstar Add-A-Wire](https://venstar.com/thermostats/accessories/add-a-wire/) (or equivalent) or
  - Run a new common wire (might make more sense to just run a new 18/5 or more bundle)

If there is not a common terminal on your A/C, you'll need to find the wiring diagram and locate the 24v transformer. Pull a common wire off the negative side of the secondary side (24v) of the transformer and connect to common terminal of Nest (or use Venstar Add-A-Wire). You'll need to verify that the added load of the Nest won't exceed the VA rating of the transformer (it shouldn't). If this is over your head - call an electrician.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming.